# Running Jupyter on Bluemix virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, jupyter

I have set up a virtual machine on Bluemix. I want to set up Jupyter Notebooks on it. I followed the tutorial here how to set up Jupyter on a VM.
http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html

It all worked until I got the below, when I try to connect to the below address, entering the public IP like https//:xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8888/ I get message unable to connect.

VM is Ubuntu 14.04. In setting up the VM, I could only select Security Groups: default , and network Private.

Any ideas what the issue may be ?

[command line message on bluemix VM that bluemix is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyrpE.png)

Comment: do you mean http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8888/ ?

Comment: The message says "The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/" . My public IP is 129.41.149.69, and I am entering the following in the browser : [https://129.41.149.69:8888/](https://129.41.149.69:8888/) using chrome or firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is to disable firewall in your Ubuntu server:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

Now a more detailed explanation and alternative solution.

The default security group for VMs deployed in the Bluemix US South region allows any incoming/outgoing port.

On the other hand, firewall is also enabled by default in the Ubuntu server and only port 22 is open.

A more elegant solution would be to open only ports that you want to expose, for example port 8888:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 8888/tcp
```

You can then check ports opened with the command:

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

**Important**: the answer here is valid only for VMs created in the Bluemix US South region. For VMs created in the Bluemix United Kingdom region check the product documentation to better understand security groups.

Comment: Darragh, you may not have points to up vote the answer, but you can accept it. There should be a check mark below the down arrow for the answer you want to accept. Here is more details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex. The below did it. I believe on AWS, that step is handled by step 3 of the link I posted, and done like below in Bluemix. 
Brilliant, really appreciate the fast response. (I don't have enough points to upvote)

```
sudo ufw allow 8888/tcp
```